# install rails4 without any documents in RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I am currently using Ubuntu with RVM installed already.
My question is how I install rails4 without any ri and rdoc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Comment: what is the difference between using gem to install rails and using rvm to install rails?

Comment: rvm doesn't install gems for you, it creates environments for each ruby, where your gems are stored (called gemset)

Comment: rvm does install rails for you when you use installer with `--rails` flag and then the second answer solves your problem

Comment: thanks, @mpapis, I wasn't aware of this (btw, thanks for RVM ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also force the `--no-ri --no-rdoc` options system wide by adding a .gemrc file into your home folder with the following content `gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc`